# Only have Increasing Values in a Column vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm writing a Macro and I need to scrub the data a bit before going into other steps. One of the things I need is to have ONLY increasing or equal values in column M.

```
M(Current Data)     M (What is Needed)
0                   0
0                   0
8055                8055
8055                8055
0                   8055
0                   8055
0                   8055
611                 8055
611                 8055
0                   8055
0                   8055
0                   8055
500                 8055
500                 8055
3065                8055
8394                8394
8300                8394
8000                8394
8194                8394

=if(M2<M1,M1,M2)
```

I've tried all sorts of IF formulas such as the one above but, as you can probably see when I hit 2 zeros in a row the formulas is no longer a solution. I've tried searching for the answer relentlessly and I'm sure its out there but, I guess I'm not sure how to word it appropriately. Any help is appreciated. Have a great day!

Comment: No need for a macro. Assuming original values in col A and new values in col B then in B2 put `=MAX(A2,B1)` and drag down

Comment: Alternate form of using the `MAX()` function would be `=MAX(A$2:A2)` filled down as necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a macro then:

```
Sub NeverDecrease()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To N
        If Cells(i, "M").Value < Cells(i - 1, "M").Value Then
            Cells(i, "M").Value = Cells(i - 1, "M").Value
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You've skipped a couple steps, I think this will do the trick: `Sub NeverDecrease()
    Dim N, i, Temp, change As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
    change = 1
    Do Until change = 0
        change = 0
        For i = 2 To N
            If Cells(i, "M").Value < Cells(i - 1, "M").Value Then
                Temp = Cells(i, "M").Value
                Cells(i, "M").Value = Cells(i - 1, "M").Value
                Cells(i - 1, "M") = Temp
                change = change + 1
            End If
        Next i
    Loop
End Sub`